# How to get two separate emails from an if statement?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to setup an email monitoring task, this would be ran every morning to ensure certain morning tasks have been completed successfully.  The code checks for any file(s) under 5 KB and it would send an email showing the name of the file(s) and the size.  I have been able to get a successful return email of the files over 5 KB but when I add a test text file about 1 KB in size, the results are non-existence.  The other issue is when I do remove the 1 KB text file and rerun the script, the email still tells me there is a file of 1 KB.  How do I rectify my script?  Is the IF statement the way to go for this?  Or should I use the `try`/`catch`/`finally` commands?

```cs
<#  Email  #>

$smptServer = '127.0.0.1'
$to = 'test@test.com'
$from = 'test@test.com'
$subject = 'Test Backup Status'

<#  File Paths  #>

$date = Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMdd"
$time = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)

$files1 =  Get-ChildItem -Path "\\testserver\F$\Test_Backups\$date\Test_Test\" -File -recurse | Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -ge $time)}
$files2 =  Get-ChildItem -Path "\\testserver\F$\Test_Backups\$date\Test_Test\" -File -recurse | Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -ge $time)}

<#  Email for No Error Body  #>

$body1 = "<b>!!   No Errors have been found.   !!</b>"

$body1 += "<table><tr><td><b>Filename</b></td></tr>"

foreach ($file1 in $files1) {
    if ($file1) {
        $body1 += "<tr>  <td>" + "<b> $($file1.Name) at $($file1.Length/1MB) MB </b>" + "<tr>  <td>" + $($file1.Directory) + "<tr>  <td>" + $($file1.LastWriteTime) + "</td>  </tr>"
    }
}

foreach ($file2 in $files2) {
    if ($file2) {
        $body1 += "<tr>  <td>" + "<b> $($file2.Name) at $($file2.Length/1MB) MB </b>" + "<tr>  <td>" + $($file2.Directory) + "<tr>  <td>" + $($file2.LastWriteTime) + "</td>  </tr>"
    }
}

$body1 += "</table>"

<#  Email for Error Body  #>

$body2 = "<b>!!ERROR!!    These files have failed to transfer    !!ERROR!!</b>"


$body2 += "<table><tr><td><b>Filename</b></td></tr>"

foreach ($file1 in $files1) {
    if ($file1.Length -lt 5kb) {
        $body2 += "<tr>  <td>" + "<b> $($file1.Name) and $($file1.Length/1MB) MB </b>" + "<tr>  <td>" + $($file1.Directory) + "<tr>  <td>" + $($file1.LastWriteTime) + "</td>  </tr>"
    }
}

foreach ($file2 in $files2) {
    if ($file2.Length -lt 5kb) {
        $body2 += "<tr>  <td>" + "<b> $($file2.Name) and $($file2.Length/1MB) MB </b>" + "<tr>  <td>" + $($file2.Directory) + "<tr>  <td>" + $($file2.LastWriteTime) + "</td>  </tr>"
    }
}

$body2 += "</table>"

$AllFiles1 = "$files1 -and $files2"
$AllFiles2 = "$files1.Length -lt 5mb -and $files2.Length -lt 5mb"


if ($AllFile2){
        Send-MailMessage -To $to -From $from -Body $body2 -BodyAsHtml -SmtpServer $smptServer -Subject  $subject
}
elseif ($AllFile1){
        Send-MailMessage -To $to -From $from -Body $body1 -BodyAsHtml -SmtpServer $smptServer -Subject  $subject
}
```

I should expect the error-ed file names at the size, location and timestamp, but I do not get anything except the title, !!ERROR!!    These files have failed to transfer    !!ERROR!!.   As the for the section BODY1, I do get the correct reply, but only if it is for the first run.  If there is an issue, and the error-ed file is removed and the script is reran the same issue comes back as before the title only returns, !!ERROR!!    These files have failed to transfer    !!ERROR!!.

EDIT** Updated the script to reflect the comments.

Comment: You've defined `$size`, but you never use it anywhere - that's probably the (primary) source of your problem :)

Comment: Wouldn't the $file1.Length -lt 5kb be similar as $size?  I have taken out the $size as I do not think it has any meaning, but I could be wrong there.

Comment: Your last `if` and `elseif` will always be false since `$AllFile1` is never defined. Also, you shouldn't use the same condition in an `elseif` that you use in an `if` because the `elseif` block will never run.

Comment: Why are there `,2` inside of the `$()` sub-expressions?

Comment: I made a change to last if elseif statement.  I have added '$AllFiles2 = "$files1.Length -lt 5kb -and $files2.Length -lt 5kb"' and added 'elseif ($AllFile2)'.  Also added the '-File' to my UNC paths.  Upon running the script, no errors came back but no email for the response.

Comment: The ,2 was for rounding decimal point to 2, but I have eliminated those as they did not work.

Comment: You made a variable called `$AllFiles2`. You must use `$AllFiles2` in your `if` statement. `$AllFile2` is not a defined variable. You can't just drop the `s` from the variable name.

Comment: I have rearranged my last if/elseif statement, due to the if part will always respond with the list of files regardless of size.  Since then, I have tested the rearranged if/elseif statement with a text file of 1KB, it responds as it should but when I delete the text file and rerun the script the email will respond with the IF and not the elseif email.  I have tried clearing my variables but that doesn't work.

Comment: I am sure my last if/elseif statement is the cause of my issue.  I cannot understand why the statement is not going to the elseif statement; even though, there are no files under 5kb.  All the other files are at least 100mb or more.   The if statement is the only part that gets continuously emailed not the else if.